# uglifier not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

```
config/application.rb
...
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/images" 
...


config/environment.rb
...
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
...

My gemfile
...
gem 'uglifier'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  #gem 'uglifier'
end
...

environment/production.rb
....
    config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
    config.assets.css_compressor = :scss
    config.assets.compress = false
...
```

I have my javascript files in app/assets/javascripts. My javascript files are not getting  compressed. Followed this url http://dev.mensfeld.pl/category/rails3/ to workout compression.

Thanks for any directions.

Answer (score 11):

In environment/production.rb:

```
...
config.assets.compress = true
...
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, & after much tearing of hair, discovered that you *must* change an asset file in order to trigger compression.

Seems that compression relies on asset file mtime, which makes sense, since one of the problems the asset pipeline intends to overcome is (from the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)):

> ... when static assets are deployed with each new release of code, the mtime of all these files changes, forcing all remote clients to fetch them again, even when the content of those assets has not changed.

Answer (score 2):

use this command:

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUP=assets assets:precompile
```