# Rails not minifying JS even though I set uglifier

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

I configured JS and CSS compressor for a project but I'm not noticing real minification of the Javascript files.

In my `production.rb` I have:

```yml
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

CSS seems to be all minified (not only bundled together).

I'm deploying to Heroku and I notice that it precompile my assets and it's probably got some GZip compression too.

But somehow JS files still got tons of spaces, variables all kept their default name, so I guess it's only bundling all files in `application.js`.

Am I getting something wrong or that's the expected output? Should I configure something apart if I want real minification of those files?

What I want is something similar to what is produced in http://jscompress.com/ or what is found on the [minified jQuery version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js).

Thanks!

Comment: You are saying that your browser on a production url shows un-minified js and css files right? Because if you are just talking about your development environment, it is expected that you would see un-minified assets.

Comment: Yes, I'm not talking about my local (development).
I'm talking about my production environment. On Heroku, with Production settings, together with Staging environment. They both got un-minified JS. CSS looks fine (minified).

Comment: @MilesStanfield, I discovered I was modifying the wrong JS files to trigger the compression. That is a necessary step to trigger the compression, otherwise Rails will use the cache and it won't trigger it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered I was modifying a Javascript that was not on the assets pipeline, therefore the compression/minification wouldn't trigger.

When I modified the correct file (being loaded on `application.js`, the minification triggered correctly [0].

So, **always remember to modify a Javascript file** [that is being loaded on the assets pipeline] **so you trigger the compressor**, otherwise Rails will use the cached javascript files and they won't be compressed.

[0] *Watch also for invalid chars:* UglifyJS ended up failing because of a comment in the first line of a `.js` file. But after I removed the comment (`<!-- (comment) ... ->`), it worked properly and I could see the `application.js` minified in staging. More about it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35751343/135767.

Comment: This is totally wrong. You do not have to modify a file to "trigger" asset compilation, whatever "trigger" means in this context.

Comment: I didn't said compilation. Compilation is always triggered.
I said **compression**. Compression or minification is only triggered when an asset is modified (and therefore it's mtime). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7988689/135767 for more details.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong and I'll happily edit or delete my answer.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, your entire question and answer is wrong and has no value. Assets are **precompiled** via `rake assets:precompile`, and compressions happens at that time. The idea of "triggering" asset compilation by modifying a file makes no sense. Even if a file's mtime was somehow relevant, **use `touch <file>`**. Adding and removing garbage lines from a file just to update its mtime is insane.

Comment: I didn't add lines, I just edited a file with `touch`.

Heroku would `precompile` files but they weren't being compressed with Uglifier until I _touched_ a file in the assets pipeline. I believe it is due to cache.

The problem I had with the comment in the file is just a side node, because `<` fails in UglifyJS if it's included in the beginning of the fil. It has nothing to do with the main solution to the problem, it's just a common issue with compression.